# Comparing the elements of two tuples in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, tuples

I have a question. I have a list given below

```
a = [([a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]),
   ([o, p, q, r], [s, t, u, v])]
```

where all alphabets are variables and hold a value. I want to compare (compute f1 score) the variables a and e, b and f, c and g, d and h, o and s, p and t, q and u, r and v, and also store the result in a list with 4 elements which is like the first element of the list contains the result of a and e, the second element stores the result of b and f, and so on. How can I do it using a for loop ? I am using this

```
eq = []
for first, second in a:
for i in range(4):
    fir = first[i]                 #Can be prediction in place of cure
    sec = second[i]

    equal = fir = sec
    # print(equal)
    eq[i].append(equal)
```

But it is giving an error.

```
     24         equal = fir = sec
     25         # print(equal)
     ---> 26         eq[i].append(equal)
     27 
     28 print(eq[0])

     IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can anybody help me with this ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure you tag your question with proper labels (programming language, relevant technologies etc). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: You have eight pairs. There are eight comparison results. How do you want to convert them into a list of four?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/68053694/4046632 Is this some homework? Or duplicate account?

Answer (score 0):

A few things in your code:

- `a = [([a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]), ([o, p, q, r], [s, t, u, v])]` I assume you do not intend to override variable `a` when initializing, so I will use `arr` instead.
- `equal = fir = sec` For comparison you need `==`.
- `append` inserts at the end of the list. So you don't need to index list (like  `eq[i]`) before insertion. If, however, you want to make two lists, you first need to declare `eq[i]` as a list, like `eq[0]  = []; eq[0].append(equal)`.
- "also store the result in a list with 4 elements" - The list would have 8 elements, not 4 - first 4 from `first` and next 4 from `second`.

Code:

```
arr = [([a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]),
       ([o, p, q, r], [s, t, u, v])]

eq = []

for first, second in arr:
    for i in range(4):
        fir = first[i]
        sec = second[i]

        equal = fir == sec
        eq.append(equal)
print(eq)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes that I listed in the code. There is a cleaner way to do it, but for the learning purpose I reuse your code.

```
a = [(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'f', 'c', 'h']),
     (['o', 'p', 'q', 'r'], ['s', 't', 'q', 'v'])]

eq = [[], []] # to make it clearer

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    first, second = a[i]
    for j in range(0, len(first)):
        fir = first[j]
        sec = second[j]
        equal = fir == sec # wrong operator: = instead of ==
        eq[i].append(equal) # wrong index, should be outer loop counter

print(eq)
```